# Given any x in I and positive epsilon

Tags: quantifiers

I need to write the statement "Given any x in I and positive epsilon" symbolically.

What is confusing is I know you can't the same variable for two different quantifiers and I don't think I can say I∈x ε∈x. Can anyone help clear this up for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $ \forall x \in I \; \text{and} \; \; \forall \epsilon > 0 $

Comment: thanks! that really help.